# Why wrap a FileReader with a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io

One could read from a txt file using a FileReader object. Why wrap it with a BufferedReader?

Comment: The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) of the class explains this: *Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So it's just faster/more efficient, by adding a buffering mechanism on top of the actual reading?

Comment: "just" faster and more efficient are pretty good reasons to me.